# How to view pdf response from post request in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm getting a pdf file from an API in response to a post request

code

```
export const getParkingReciept = (bookindId) => {
    return async function (dispatch, getState) {
        try {

            const TOKEN = getState().Auth.token;
            const formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("booking_id", bookindId);

            var config = {
                method: 'post',
                url: `${BASE_URL}parking-space/booking/receipt`,
                headers: {
                             'Accept': 'application/json',
                             'Authorization': `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
                             'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                         },
                        data: formdata
            };

            const response = await axios(config)
            console.log("responseParkingReciept", response)


        } catch (e) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Eventhough I get a response with content type:"Application/pdf" I don't see any link or blob in response
[image]

But I do get an Image when I try from postman.
[image]
What am I missing ? I dont see any link or blob in response

Comment: In your request header you are accepting 'application/json'. Update it with 'application/pdf'.

Comment: @MazedulIslam I used application/json in postman as well, it works fine in postman

Comment: Hi @Arjun, did you get any solution on this. I am facing same issue. I am getting pdf as response for my get api.